# Issue while performing the Get-Object Operation in S3 using AWSCLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to perform Get-Object operation in AWS. To achieve this, I have followed the below link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html

By following this, I have tried executing the below command from my CLI:

**aws s3api get-object --bucket test-bucket-1 --key test-object sample.zip**

where,

**test-bucket-1** is the name of my bucket,
**test-object** is the name of my object,
**sample.zip** is the zip file where I want the contents to be downloaded to.

By doing this, I get the following error:

***An error occurred (Invalid Token) when calling the GetObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.***

The user by whom I am performing this action has the following policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
```

}

Am I passing any parameter wrong? Please let me know.

Comment: Did you execute `aws configure` before running that command ? If so , you may need to review policies attached with the IAM user that you are using .

Comment: Yes, I ran it. Set the AWS access and secret keys, specified region and output format.

Comment: Great ! Do you give this user permissions to access test-bucket-1 ? If no , i will post an answer and i will give you policy.

Comment: No Abdennour. I didn't give any permissions to access the bucket.

Comment: Check your the time on the machine you're running this command on is in sync, if it's off you get a similar error.

Comment: Actually Abdennour, I am running as a user with Admin rights

Comment: Ok i will post an answer now and it will work . Just try it 

Comment: Sure Abdennour. I will. Thanks.

Comment: Please try now :) All the best of luck ! I put the answer.

Comment: Please run aws-cli with the --debug option.  Find the XML response from S3 with `<Error><Code>InvalidToken</Code>...` and show us the rest of that XML, please.  There should be no sensitive information in the XML.  The RequestId and HostId values may look like they might be, but they are not.

Answer (score 2):

Even you set the region when you ran `aws configure`, you will need to set it again with this command (set the region of bucket ) :

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket test-bucket-1 --key test-object sample.zip --region <BUCKET-REGION>
```

It seems weird , but I encountered similar issue before, and the resolution is what I explained.

Of course, the answer assumes you have the right permissions (policy) to access the bucket since you are saying you have Admin access.

Comment: Hi Abdennour, I tried the answer you provided. Below is my command :  
 aws s3api get-object --bucket test-bucket-1 --key test-object sample.zip --region us-east-2. But, I still encounter the same issue.

Comment: Weird ! I will delete the answer . Nevertheless, I push you to take this answer as a note. Because this info I got throughout my preparation to AWS certifications and I found it valid.

Comment: @Abdennour. Your command is correct. However, note that you are copying the object "test-object" and writing it to "sample.zip".

Comment: Most likely the error is caused by the clock on his computer being wrong.

Comment: @JohnHanley If you can help him by elaborating more , I will be grateful .

Comment: Where you are located does not matter as times are the same in GMT. What I am trying to say is that the time on your computer is wrong which does not match the time at Amazon (in GMT). This will generate the invalid token error.

Comment: Execute this command. Replace with your bucket name. "aws s3 ls s3://mybucket". Do you get an error?

Comment: Did you check your computer's clock first? The time must be very close to the actual time.

Comment: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-change-date-and-time-on-windows-10.html

Comment: Hanley, the time on my computer is correct. I have re-checked it.

Comment: Try "aws iam get-user". Then post the IAM policy for that user in your question.

Comment: I am getting the same error when I run the above command too. I have Admin Access and IAMUserChangePassword. However, I edited my question to reflect the policy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159260/discussion-between-prudhvi-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Just for information, the bucket which I am trying for is a private bucket.

Comment: What is your definition of a private bucket? The S3 bucket policy makes no difference when you are using IAM User credentials with admin rights. Create new credentials and rerun "aws configure".